# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2' macOS

Tags: python, postgresql, macos

Each time I run my script, I get this error
 `% python new_monthly_donations.py  Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/bdohman/Desktop/uway payments/scripts/new_monthly_donations.py", line 2, in <module> import psycopg2 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'`

I'm new to python, relatively new to development on a mac.

I installed python through the dmg. I have python version 3.9.6
I installed psycopg2 by doing `pip3 install psycopg2` and `pip3 install psycopg2-binary`

Each time I run my script I get the error above.

The script is being run from a folder on my desktop.

Here is the info on psycopg2

`pip3 show psycopg2-binary

Name: psycopg2-binary
Version: 2.9.5
Summary: psycopg2 - Python-PostgreSQL Database Adapter
Home-page: https://psycopg.org/
Author: Federico Di Gregorio
Author-email: fog@initd.org
License: LGPL with exceptions
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:

% pip3 show psycopg2
Name: psycopg2
Version: 2.9.5
Summary: psycopg2 - Python-PostgreSQL Database Adapter
Home-page: https://psycopg.org/
Author: Federico Di Gregorio
Author-email: fog@initd.org
License: LGPL with exceptions
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
`

I also followed the other steps here > https://rogulski.it/blog/install-psycopg2-on-apple-m1/

I installed pyscopg2 pyscopg2-binary on my mac using pip3 and I expected my script to not through the module not found error.

Comment: Have you tried pip install ?

Comment: 1) Did you install to the OS system or to a virtualenv? 2) Is "The script is being run from a folder on my desktop" running the program in a virtualenv or not? If a virtualenv is it the one you installed `psycopg2` in?

Comment: replace "python" to "python3" and report back

Comment: that fixed it @rasjani - i used python3 and the script worked. thanks!!

Comment: This was not a virtualenv.

I had done pip install too.

Answer (score 0):

the fix here was to do python3 filename.py.